# Comportamento estranho do BaseAdapter no android

Tags: android, listview

Tenho uma `ListView` com `CheckBox`, essa `ListView` é organizada com duas List no adapter, uma que seriam todos os itens, e a outra apenas com os selecionados.

Criei um `CheckBox` para adicionar a funcionalidade de marcar/desmarcar todos, assim sendo, quando clicar em marcar, adiciono na lista de selecionados todos os itens, caso contrário crio uma nova instância da lista, até então tudo ok.

Porém, se eu clicar em um `CheckBox` dentro da `ListView` também mando adicionar/remover na lista de selecionados, e chamo o notifySetDataChanged() para atualizar a tela, o estranho é que também está sendo removido da lista principal, o que faz com que a tela seja redesenhada sem o item, e não apenas desmarcá-lo.

Em nenhum momento do código eu faço alguma alteração na lista principal, somente na lista de selecionados, e mesmo assim, quando vou adicionar/remover da lista de selecionados está sendo removido da lista principal, alguém sabe o que pode estar ocorrendo?

O código do adapter é este:

```
public class ListViewNaoEnviadosAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<NaoEnviado> naoEnviados;
    private List<NaoEnviado> selecionados;
    private CheckBox chkEnviarSmsNaoEnviados, chkNaoEnviadosMarcarTodos;
    private TextView tvTotalNaoEnviados;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private final Context ctx;

    public ListViewNaoEnviadosAdapter(Context ctx, List<NaoEnviado> naoEnviados) {
        this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.naoEnviados = naoEnviados;
        this.selecionados = naoEnviados;

        chkNaoEnviadosMarcarTodos = (CheckBox) ((MainActivity) ctx)
                .findViewById(R.id.chkNaoEnviadosMarcarTodos);
        chkNaoEnviadosMarcarTodos.setChecked(true);

        tvTotalNaoEnviados = (TextView) ((MainActivity) ctx)
                .findViewById(R.id.tvTotalNaoEnviados);
        tvTotalNaoEnviados.setText(String.valueOf(selecionados.size()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return naoEnviados.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return naoEnviados.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return naoEnviados.get(position).getId();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        NaoEnviadosHelper naoEnviadosHelper = new NaoEnviadosHelper();
        final NaoEnviado naoEnviado = naoEnviados.get(position);
        final Telefone tel = new Telefone(ctx);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_sms_nao_enviados, null);
            naoEnviadosHelper.nome = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSmsNaoEnviadosNome);
            naoEnviadosHelper.telefone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSmsNaoEnviadosTelefone);
            naoEnviadosHelper.descFalha = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSmsNaoEnviadosDescFalha);
            naoEnviadosHelper.enviarSms = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chkEnviarSmsNaoEnviados);
            convertView.setTag(naoEnviadosHelper);
        } else {
            naoEnviadosHelper = (NaoEnviadosHelper) convertView.getTag();
        }
        naoEnviadosHelper.nome.setText(naoEnviado.getNome().trim());
        naoEnviadosHelper.telefone.setText(tel.formataTelefone(naoEnviado.getTelefone()));
        naoEnviadosHelper.descFalha.setText(naoEnviado.getTipoFalha());
        naoEnviadosHelper.enviarSms.setChecked(selecionados.contains(naoEnviado));

        //Checkbox marcar/desmarcar todos na tela...
        chkNaoEnviadosMarcarTodos = (CheckBox) ((MainActivity) ctx)
                .findViewById(R.id.chkNaoEnviadosMarcarTodos);
        chkNaoEnviadosMarcarTodos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selecionados = new ArrayList<NaoEnviado>();
                if (chkNaoEnviadosMarcarTodos.isChecked()) {
                    selecionados = naoEnviados;
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        //Checkbox marcar/desmarcar para envio
        chkEnviarSmsNaoEnviados = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chkEnviarSmsNaoEnviados);
        chkEnviarSmsNaoEnviados.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!chkEnviarSmsNaoEnviados.isChecked()) {
                    selecionados.add(naoEnviado);
                } else {
                    //Aqui acontece o problema, quando mando remover desta lista, também
                    // é removido da lista principal (naoEnviados)
                    selecionados.remove(naoEnviado);

                    //Se um elemento foi removido eu desmarco o checkbox marcartodos
                    chkNaoEnviadosMarcarTodos.setChecked(false);
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        tvTotalNaoEnviados.setText(String.valueOf(selecionados.size()));

        return convertView;
    }

    private class NaoEnviadosHelper {
        TextView telefone, nome, descFalha;
        CheckBox enviarSms;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por aquilo que me dá a perceber você não tem duas lista mas apenas uma.
Ter duas variáveis com nomes diferentes só por si não garante que o valor delas seja diferente.

Nesta parte do código

```
public ListViewNaoEnviadosAdapter(Context ctx, List<NaoEnviado> naoEnviados) {
    this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.naoEnviados = naoEnviados;
    this.selecionados = naoEnviados;

    .....
    .....
```

e nesta

```
chkNaoEnviadosMarcarTodos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        selecionados = new ArrayList<NaoEnviado>();
        if (chkNaoEnviadosMarcarTodos.isChecked()) {
            selecionados = naoEnviados;
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

ao fazer `selecionados = naoEnviados;` você não está a copiar o conteúdo de `naoEnviados` para `selecionados` está apenas a fazer com que variável `selecionados` aponte para o mesmo conteúdo que aponta `naoEnviados`.
Qualquer alteração feita numa é repercutida na outra.

Comment: Obrigado @ramaral pela ajuda, porém tentei efetuar o preenchimento da lista manualmente, e mesmo assim, continua com o problema. tem mais algum detalhe que possa estar ocasionando o problema?

Comment: Como vez esse preenchimento?

Comment: Fiz com um foreach: for(NaoEnviado n : naoEnviados) ..., e dentro dele, adicionei a lista de selecionados, selecionados.add(n);

Comment: Verifiquei aqui, e você estava com razão, no construtor da classe, eu fazia essa referência das duas listas, isso estava ocasionando o problema, modifiquei no construtor, e agora está ok, obrigado @ramaral mais uma vez.